# How can I limit a string to just the first word or the text upbeat not including the first semicolon?

Tags: c#, string, limit

I have a **string** that contains words like these:

```
var a = "abc";
var a = "abc;";
var a = "abc; def";
var a = "abc def";
var a = "abc; def";
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could create a new string that would in all these cases (including if the termination character was a period or anything other than a-z and A-Z), consist only of "abc"?

Comment: So you want to stop getting letters if you run into a space or a semicolon? Anything else (what about tabs? carriage returns? line feeds? full stops?)?

Comment: What does `Char.IsLetter` do? What does `TakeWhile` do?

Comment: Good point. I need to stop getting letters if I see a space, semicolon, tab or full stop.  In fact anything that's not a normal letter

Comment: Do you only want `"abc"` or also `"def"`?

Comment: just "abc" or if another string then anything up until the termination character which could be .,; or anything that's not an a-z or A-Z character

Comment: `Regex` could be useful(assuming it is the English alphabet and ASCII).

Comment: In another words, you want to keep only the letters, removing the spaces and semicolon characters? `String.Join("", Regex.Split(item, @"[^a-z]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))`

Comment: Or you also need to remove the "def"? your problem isn't clear...

Comment: `var separators = "; "; Console.WriteLine((item + separators).Split(separators.ToCharArray())[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few examples:

```
// Using regex, assuming English alphabet and ASCII
var a = Regex.Split("abc;abc", "[^a-zA-Z]").First();

// Using System.Linq, preferable!
var b = string.Concat("abc abc".TakeWhile(c => char.IsLetter(c)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions:

1. with a regular expression:

   ```
   public static string GetLettersAtTheStart(string s) {
       return Regex.Match(s, "^[a-zA-Z]+").Value;
   }
   ```

   This regex matches all the characters that is in the set `[a-zA-Z]` that is at the start of the string.
2. with `TakeWhile`:

   ```
   public static string GetLettersAtTheStart(string s) {
       return string.Join("", s.TakeWhile(char.IsLetter));
   }
   ```

   This basically says that keep taking characters from the string while it is a letter, and then joining them with an empty string.

Usage:

```
GetLettersAtTheStart("abc; def") // "abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop the string after any non-letter character you can use this function.

```
public static string limitString(string text) {

        string newString = "";

        foreach (char character in text) {

            if (Char.IsLetter(character)) {

                newString += character;

            } else {

                break;

            }

        }

        return newString;

}
```

Example usage:

```
limitString("abc; def");
```

Would result in the string `abc`.

If you want to stop the string after certain characters, this function should work.

```
public static string limitString(string text, List<char> characters) {

        foreach (char character in characters) {

            text = text.Split(character)[0];

        }

        return text;

}
```

Example usage:

```
List<char> limChars = new List<char>() { ';' };

limitString("test;", limChars);
```

Would produce the string `test`, you can also limit more than one character by adding more items to the list.

Comment: Why not using `string.Split` it has an overload to receive more than one separator... Also, your function will return result from the last used separator which might be not correct... You want in first place to separate using all separators...

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use regular expression. You can do that with `@"^[a-zA-Z]*"`. Your code could look like the following:

```
string getString(String str)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]*");
    return regex.Match(str).Value;
}
```

You could also iterate each character checking if it is from alphabetical:

```
string getString2(String str)
{
    string resultString = "";
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter(c))
            resultString += c;
        else
            break;
    }
    return resultString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As one mentioned in comments, you can use `TakeWhile`. It will look like this:

```
string.Concat(a.TakeWhile(char.IsLetter))
```

the output will always be:

```
abc
```